# dataTables in phantomjs selecting latest created row using

Tags: javascript, datatable, phantomjs, shiny

I have created a dataTable in my shiny R app.Now I am making a automated testing tool for this App by using phantomJS.The login page has a dataTable to store the sessions of a particular user.The dataTable has three columns :- "userID","description" and "timeStamp". I need to select the latest row created from the dataTable probably by making a function.This can be done in my opinion by using the time stamp or row index. 
Can I get some snippet and confirmation if that's the right thing to do?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then post what you have tried.